# How to initialize data in a Vue.js component from SQL query

Tags: javascript, sqlite, vue.js, vuejs2, electron

I am writing a simple tag browser application using Electron, SQlite and Vue.js. On application startup, I need to populate a HTML table with all rows from an SQL table.

I'm having trouble initializing the data in my *Vue* component however. When I start the application, I see no results. However, once I refresh the window all the results are there and the table rows are successfully created.

What is the best way to get an async request (in this case an SQLite query) to initialize the data of a *Vue.js* component?

My attempt so far (irrelevant code removed)

**model.js**

```
module.exports.getAll = function(table, callback) {
    const sql = `SELECT * from ${table}`;

    dbConnect();
    db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
        callback && callback(rows);
    });
   db.close();
}
```

**FileTable.vue**

```
<template>  
...
            <tr v-for="file in listings">
                <td>{{ file.filename }}</td>
                <td>{{ file.type }}</td>
                <td>{{ file.size }}</td>
                <td>{{ file.path }}</td>
            </tr>
...
</template>

<script>
    import model from '../../model.js';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                listings: {}
            }
        },

        methods: {
            initListings: function() {
                model.getAll('files', rows => {this.listings = rows});
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.initListings();
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
module.exports.getAll = function (table) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const sql = `SELECT * from ${table}`

    dbConnect();
    db.all(sql, (err, rows) => {
      db.close()
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
    })
  })
}

<template>  
  ...
  <tr v-for="file in listings">
    <td>{{ file.filename }}</td>
    <td>{{ file.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ file.size }}</td>
    <td>{{ file.path }}</td>
  </tr>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  import model from '../../model.js'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        listings: []
      }
  },
  methods: {
    async initListings () {
      this.listings = await model.getAll('files')
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.initListings()
  }
</script>
```

Comment: There is something weird happening when I try this. It straight up kills the entire application. I can get as far as adding the Promise to the model.getAll function before it breaks everything. Screenshot: 
 https://i.imgur.com/K7QgCJa.png (addFile is a function further up in model.js)